# Office 365 Unified Api (beta version)

Tags: office365

I tried to implement O365 unified api(beta version). I successfully got all the groups, However I faced problems when trying to get files of a particular group.

**The error message is " UnAuthorized (401)" .**

When I checked in fiddler it returns an error from server in webview.

I have already given permissions (read all site collections
, all groups, all files), still file access is not working.

If anyone knows how to fix this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**First, let's ensure we are using the correct method:**

As per the docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/groups-rest-operations, ensure that you are using this method :

***List all files and folders***
Get a list of all of the immediate files and folders in a group.
Required scope: Group.Read.All

```html
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/{tenant}/groups('{groupId}')/files
```

***Response***
Returns the children collection of files and folders in the group, if successful. Note that this doesn't return the children of the immediate folders in the group.

**Sample request**

```html
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contoso.com/groups('c75831bd-fad3-4191-9a66-280a48528679')/files
```

**Second, Let's rule out some peculiarities of the API Preview/Beta mode:**

Please review and validate the following 3 caveats against your testing scenario https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-rest-api-release-notes :

> **No instant access to content after creation**
>
> Unified groups can be created immediately through a POST on the group
>   entity. However, for a unified group that is created through the
>   unified API, access to the associated content will not be readily
>   available. Apps will be able to start adding content to the group
>   (files, conversations, and events) after a set period of time, as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> For conversations and events, up to 40 minutes after group creation
> For files, up to 24 hours after group creation
> ```
>
> Until that time, attempts to update the unified group with content
>   will result in a 500 HTTP error response. For proof-of-concept
>   applications that are using the Office 365 unified APIs, we recommend
>   that you use Outlook or Outlook Web App to create unified group if
>   immediate access to the content is required.
>
> **Policy**
>
> Using the Office 365 unified APIs to create and name a unified group
>   bypasses any unified group policies that are configured through
>   Outlook Web App. For proof-of-concept applications that use the Office
>   365 unified APIs, we recommend that you use Outlook or Outlook Web App
>   to create unified groups.
>
> **Permission scopes**
>
> The Office 365 unified API exposes two permission scopes for unified
>   groups:
>
> ```
> Group.Read.All
> Group.ReadWrite.All
> ```
>
> These scopes provide access to group management functions (enumerating
>   groups, enumerating group members) as well as access to content in the
>   group (conversations and events). However, in order to access files in
>   a unified group, you must also request the Sites.Read.All or
>   Site.ReadWrite.All permission scope. For more information about these
>   permission scopes, see Get started with Office 365 unified API
>   (preview).

**Finally, check if there's anything different about the Group you are querying against**
If you review the Group in Graph Explorer, do you see any differences in the group metadata between it and Groups elsewhere and outside of your testing tenancy? There may be a smoking gun property that stands out.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, is because you don't have Site.Read.All permission, this is a temporary requirement to access group files.